# PDF Sharp setting font styles

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I have a font dialog to let user pick a font name, font size and also possibly a font style.

but this code doesn't work

```
XFont myFont = new XFont(txtP.Font.Name, txtP.Font.Size, txtP.Font.Style);
```

> Error is: Error   2   Argument 3: cannot convert from
>   'System.Drawing.FontStyle' to 'PdfSharp.Drawing.XFontStyle' /
>   Error 1   The best overloaded method match for
>   'PdfSharp.Drawing.XFont.XFont(string, double,
>   PdfSharp.Drawing.XFontStyle)' has some invalid arguments

is there a workaround on this? I would really like to let users choose Font Style also not just name and size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by

```
XFont myFont = new XFont(txtP.Font.Name, txtP.Font.Size, (PdfSharp.Drawing.XFontStyle)fontStyle);
```

Comment: Since XFontStyle and FontStyle use the same values, the cast will work.

Answer (score 0):

`XFontStyle` is an enum defined by PdfSharp. Like the error says, there is no way to convert System.Drawing.FontStyle' to 'PdfSharp.Drawing.XFontStyle'.

Options:

1. Let the user select directly from xFontStyle values.
2. Create a converter method between FontStyle and XFontStyle.

The second method is a little complicated because you have to map the values in the first enum to the second one, and as you can see they are not exactly the same, but it can be done.
[image]
[image]

Comment: A snippet from the MigraDoc source code: `public enum XFontStyle  // same values as System.Drawing.FontStyle`.
BoldItalic is just a combination of Bold and Italic.